Consider T, a set containing all subsets of X which are countable or their complement is countable. T also contains X and $\phi$. Is this a topology?
Basically the title. I have a feeling that this is not a topology and the issue would come up when I consider arbitrary union of countable subsets in T which may not be countable and the complement of this union needn't be countable either. But I am unable to come up with such an example. Kindly help. Thank you.

Please put the question n the body of the post, not just the title.

Consider any (necessarily) uncountable set $X$ and a subset $A\subseteq X$ such that both $A$ and $X\backslash A$ are uncountable. Such subset always exists (for example because $X\cong X\sqcup X$, which is true for all infinite sets under the Axiom of Choice). In that situation
$$A=\bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}$$
and so $A$ is not only a union of countable sets, but in fact of singletons. But of course it doesn't belong to our collection $T$.
A concrete example is $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=[0,1]$.
